# Adding Views/ViewModels to an ObservableCollection when using ViewModel-First MVVM Stylet framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, avalondock, stylet

**When using a ViewModel first MVVM pattern, how can you add your ViewModels to an ObservableCollection so they can be bound into another View and appear as a view?**

I’m using AvalonDock, and I’m struggling to bind the `LayoutDocument` panes in AvalonDock to my View.

I’m using Stylet as my MVVM framework, but I’ve also tagged it as Caliburn-Micro as I assume my problem is relevant to any ViewModel-First implementation of MVVM.

My test `ObservableCollection` is populated as follows:

```
        Documents = new ObservableCollection<LayoutDocument>();

        LayoutDocument layout1 = new LayoutDocument();
        layout1.Title = "New Document";
        UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
        layout1.Content = control;

        LayoutDocument layout2 = new LayoutDocument();
        layout2.Title = "New Document 2";
        HomeViewModel control2 = HomeViewModel;
        layout2.Content = control2;

        LayoutDocument layout3 = new LayoutDocument();
        layout3.Title = "New Document 3";
        HomeView control3 = HomeView;
        layout3.Content = control3;


        Documents.Add(layout1);
        Documents.Add(layout2);
        Documents.Add(layout3);
```

`UserControl1` is Initialized via `InitializeComponent()` in code behind and works perfectly. See image below (first tab).

`HomeViewModel` which is how I would like to attach them inline with Stylet requirements has been brought through the constructor and AvalonDock doesn’t seem to recognized it as a ViewModel. It just displays the URL to the ViewModel.

`HomeView` (which is a View) has had the code behind deleted, and I would have thought it would be initialized by Stylet. The object has been injected through the constructor. In AvalonDock it’s behaving as an uninitialized view so just shows nothing.

Here is the Constructor:

```
public DockingViewModel(HomeViewModel homeViewModel, HomeView homeView)
    {
        HomeViewModel = homeViewModel;
        HomeView = homeView;
        LoadInitialTabs();
    }
```

I don’t believe the issue is with AvalonDock, but here is how the views are bound.

```
<DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content , FallbackValue=#ERROR Content.title#}"></ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
```

Note in the image below of the different results when `LayoutDocuments` are created in different ways.

**How can I get this working in a ViewModel first approach, i.e. using Stylet?**

[image]

Comment: You should avoid a reference to a view in a viewmodel. If at all possible.  Which I would think it is. If something has to be in a particular view then usually it would be templated from a viewmodel in the datacontext of that view.

Comment: That is my plan, my aim is to be able to just add various ViewModels to the ObservableCollection.
I only added the two Views (one with codebehind and one without) to troubleshoot my issue.
Unless your saying that it's still bad practice to add the ViewModels to my ObservableCollection (assuming I can get it to work)?

Comment: It's usual to have an observablecollection of viewmodels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As I am using Stylet I needed to make the following changes in my View.

First, add the reference for Stylet.

```
xmlns:s="https://github.com/canton7/Stylet"
```

Second: Change the DataContent binding from:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content , FallbackValue=#ERROR Content.title#}"></ContentControl>
```

To:

```
<ContentControl s:View.Model="{Binding Content , FallbackValue=#ERROR Content.title#}"></ContentControl>
```

With Stylet, the `s:View.Model` bit automatically finds the `View` from the `ViewModel` and Initializes it.
Now, I can hold nothing but `ViewModels` in my `ObservableCollection` and it works fine/